# Vlan with multiple switches

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point, switch, vlan

I have an Asus rt-N66U with Tomato 1.28 115-EN. My goal is to separate wired and wireless traffic, so what I would like to do is attach this router with two HP 24 port managed switches.

So I have two VLAN's on the router,
VLan 1 (Default VLAN) for wired connections - Ports 1 2 3 4
VLAN 3 (Wireless VLAN) for wireless connection - Ports 1 2 3

Port 1 goes to Room 1 where they have an HP Procurve 24 port switch 1
Port 2 goes to Room 2 where they have an HP Procurve 24 port switch 2
Port 3 goes to Room 3 where they have an HP Procurve 24 port switch 3
Port 4 goes to Server room where they have an HP Procurve 24 port HUB 1

So on switch 1 I have two VLANs just like the router VLAN 1, and VLAN 3. Vlan 1(default VLAN) is used for all ports 2-23. VLAN 3 is assigned to port 1, and port 24 is assigned to VLAN1 and VLAN3. Router's port 1 connects to Switch's port 24, and Switch's port 1 connects to an EA-N66 access point. While other ports connected to ethernet devices.

I have the same setup for all other rooms. So my question is having a port with two vlans tagged and connected from the router to a switch with the same VLAN ids tagged. Would that work with what I am trying to achieve as in carrying out two vlans using one port, and then separating it on the switch?

Can I have two VLANs going from the router to switch, and will the switch recognize the same vlans?